# Creating a Handler for Dynamic Forms

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

On a few occasions now I have attempted the daunting task of creating an input form where I can allow the end user to add an unlimited amount of inventory items for management. When looking for help, I have gained a much greater understanding and improved my handling of it better through each rewrite of my script, but I am now stuck on how to handle the POST Data.

As I have been unable to find any tutorials/examples/discussions on the matter, how would would handle a dynamic form with potentially dozens of inputs in a PHP Handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to assign your fields a class, loop through them in your javascript and construct a url based on that on the client side

On the server side you could get the params and split it by string.

An example would be

```
<input type="text" class="field1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="field2" value="" />


<input type="text" class="field1" value="" />
<input type="text" class="field2" value="" />

<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

an implementation of the client side in jQuery could be something like

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
var postUrl = url + "?field1=";
    $(".field1").each(function(){
        postUrl = postUrl + $(this).val() + "_";
    });

    //do something similar for field2 also.
});
```

and in your php code you could get the params and split by the "_" character.